# Getting a 404 when trying to access my elasticsearch cluster

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I can do a request on the base url and it gets a 200 returned but when I try to leverage the search function or any thing else I get a 404. Here is the code I am using to try and access the cluster health and I get the 404.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch('https://XXXXXXX.kb.us-west-2.aws.found.io:XXXX',
                       basic_auth=('XXXXX', 'XXXXX'),
                       ca_certs=False, verify_certs=False)
print(es.cluster.health())
```

Comment: Did you try to use `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: I was going after the wrong endpoint... I was hitting the kb to es endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was so simple it's almost embarrassing to write. I was going after the Kibana endpoint instead of the Elastic search endpoint...

`https://XXXXXXX.kb.us-west-2.aws.found.io:XXXX` -- wrong

`https://XXXXXXX.es.us-west-2.aws.found.io:XXXX` -- right